# как такое меню сделать чтобы при прокрутке вниз страницы меню осталось видным вверху браузера?

Tags: html, css

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/multishop-universal-html-shop-template/full_screen_preview/20546702?_ga=2.39399907.1131930067.1597614561-1216755955.1597614472
чтобы только белая часть оставалась а самая верхняя скрывалась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.sticky {
   position: sticky;
  top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 9999; 
}
```